# Xcode 4 "Fix it" - when does it appear?

Tags: xcode4, clang-static-analyzer

I would like to know when the "Fix-it" should appear? Is it possible to make appear on all errors (and suggest a change?)
[image: Assignment when it should be comparison]
Clearly an error in my code, which "Fix-it" analyzed and detected.
But can it help me even more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Fix-it doesn't support *all* errors/warnings.  I've looked for a list of supported ones, with no such luck.  It's likely that more will be added in future releases.  It's still a very new feature, so Apple will see how things go and improve, adapt, and update.

Comment: Tnx, I asked apple (at their forums) and they will add more functionality to it in future releases.